# How upsert() works on multiple keys ? [Sequelise]

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, upsert

Suppose I have a model:

```
const Player = db.define('player', {
  // The primary key of the table.
  playerId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    primaryKey: true,
  },

  playerName: DataTypes.STRING(11),

  teamId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(32),
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'team',
      key: 'teamId',
    }
  },

  managerId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(32),
    allowNull: true,
    references: {
      model: 'manager',
      key: 'managerId',
    }
  },

});
```

If I do

```
Player.upsert(
  {
    teamId: p.teamId,
    managerId: p.managerId,
    playerName: p.name
  }
)
```

will a new player be created or an existing player with same `teamId` and `managerId` will be updated ?
How can I know which values does `upsert` look for in order to check if an entry already exists ? Does it look only for primaryKey, all the foreignKeys ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks for a primary key value just like similar SQL commands in many DBMSs.
All other fields may be equal but PK is designed to be unique to distinguish one record from another.